# Hide a javascript if user comes from an specific location

Tags: javascript, php

I want a javascript file (`<script src=" file here " >`) to be hidden if a user lets say comes from China.

How can i do it?

Comment: That would be racism, and that's not allowed on the interwebs.

Comment: Haha,gave me a good laugh but i really need to work on this now :) any help?

Comment: Install some standard geoip database? (maxmind's is quite common), and just don't output it?

Comment: you need to do this in your server

Comment: There are geoIP services that will guesstimate where a user is coming from, start there, and then create some sort of PHP code that only includes the file if the user is not from China.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Chinese and I reserve all my rights to protest. :)

Actually you have a few options, you can do it front-end or back-end.

**Front-end solution**

Use `HTML5 Geolocation` to determine the longitude and latitude of current user and check whether it's within China or not(don't forget to contain Taiwan). The defect is only modern browsers are supported, you should probably set up plan B.

```
//jQuery, ip-api is a RESTful service, do it in front-end
$.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?', function(response){
    alert(response.country);
    if(response.country === "China"){
        $.getScript("script_for_Chinese.js");
    }
});
```

**Back-end solution**

1. Check the user IP and find out if it's from China(there are a bunch of `IP to location` RESTful services)
2. Check HTTP header if the `Accept-Language` part contains string like `zh-CN` or `zh-TW`. This may also hurt the people using Chinese in other countries.

As for example requested, I won't recommend you use front-end solution or `IP-to-location` back-end solution. The only one that might work is based on http header.

```
//PHP, if the client accept Chinese, assume he is from China
if(preg_match('/(zh-CN|zh-TW|zh)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
    echo '<script src="script_for_Chinese.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a more specific code,i am a noob in this field and i do not know how to integrate it.

Comment: @Joel I added an example

Comment: thanks for the help but it needs to be with an IP ,because not so many peoples give correct information about language...

Comment: @Joel If you insist on using IP solution, using it in front-end might be better, given to there is little difference and you don't want to add extra load for your server. But there will be perceivable latency for the specific script loading. I updated the example.

Comment: Hi ,thanks very much for your time,can you please alert or echo something so i should see that the script works?i mean instead of the  embed script_for_china try to echo the country

Comment: Thanks  man,a friend of mine did on PHP but this looks much better and safer :))) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a [geolocation service](https://freegeoip.net/) but considering that you can defeat that by using a proxy (like a hacked machine in the US) somewhere else or by spoofing the request to look like it came from given location it may not do you much good in the end.